# Generating random unix timestamp for tomorrow's date

Tags: php, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to generate a random unix timestamp for the following day in PHP. Could anyone point me into the right direction as to how this could be done?

Thanks!
Frank

Comment: "Tomorrow" isn't really random. What are you up to?

Comment: I want to generate a random time in the following day in the form of a UNIX timestamp. E.g. at 05:28 the following day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a random timestamp between 12:00am and 11:59pm you can do:

```
$tomorrow0000 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('d')+1, date('Y')); // midnight tomorrow
$tomorrow2359 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('d')+2, date('Y')) - 1; // midnight next day minus 1 second

$random = mt_rand($tomorrow0000, $tomorrow2359);
```

Comment: A day is not guaranteed to have 86400 seconds...!

Comment: Incorporated the daylight savings time issue into one block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
$tomorrow_time = strtotime("tomorrow") + rand(0, 86400);
```

Basically, I get tomorrow midnight time and then add random second from 0 to 86400 (24 hours)